# List the largest and latest 20 files on a drive

Tags: find, disk-usage

I have a disk filling up which has many large files on it so I want to find only the latest and largest 20 files on the disk. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `zsh`:

```
ls -lrtd -- **/*(D.OL[1,20])
```

For the 20 largest files sorted from oldest to newest.

```
ls -lrtd -- **/*(D.OL[1,20]m-1)
```

Same but limited to files last modified in the last 24 hours. Replace `m-1` with `mh-1` for the last hour.

```
ls -lSd -- **/*(D.om[1,20])
```

for the 20 most recent files, sorted by size (smallest to largest).

```
ls -lSd -- **/*(D.om[1,20]LM+100)
```

same but limited to files larger than 100 MiB.

Note that the `L` glob qualifier works on the *apparent size* of the files, not their *disk usage* (as reported by `du` for instance).

Comment: nice! Not only do I like how you used the extended globbing, but also that you made passing arguments to `ls` safe by  separating them with `-- `.

Comment: How can I reverse the sort order? I need the largest and the newest

Comment: remove the `r` from the `ls -lrtd` in the first case, and add it to `lSd` in the second.

Comment: @markhorrocks, add/remove the `-r` (for reverse) option to `ls`.

Comment: I get no such directory error

Comment: @markhorrocks, those commands need to be run from the `zsh` shell. That's syntax specific to that shell, it won't work in any other shell.

Comment: @markhorrocks are you using zsh?

Comment: @MarcusMüller, that's spooky. Second time we write the almost identical comment within a few seconds :-)

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas quantum entanglement! Anyway, could you have a look at the comments under my answer? I might be misunderstanding what OP needs, and you seem to have a firmer grasp on it.

Answer (score 2):

Find the latest 20 files:

```
find . -type f -printf "%T@ %Tc %p\0" | sort -z -nr | head -z -n20
```

(adapted from [here](https://superuser.com/questions/294161/unix-linux-find-and-sort-by-date-modified))

Find the largest 20:

```
find . -type f -printf "%s %p\0" | sort -z -nr | head -z -n20
```

or, much simpler

```
du -ba0 | sort -nr | head -z -n20
```

you might need to add at `| tr '\0' '\n'` to the end of your pies if you want the files to newline-separated instead of zero-separated. **Note that filenames can  contain newlines, so this is in generally not a good idea**; which is why I used zero-byte separation in all the examples above (file names cannot contain zero-bytes).

Comment: Neither of those help me. I can find the latest or the largest but not both. Maybe the latest larger than a specified size might work?

Comment: huh, OK, what do you mean with "both". If two lists, one of the largest, and one of the latest, are not what you're looking for, I'm very confused about *what* it is that you're looking for. You can't sort things by *two* independent criteria at once, that makes logically no sense...

Comment: The 20 largest files may be old and the 20 latest files may be too small

Comment: yes, but which files do you then want to see?

Comment: I need to see the latest and largest files so I can see which files have filled my disk since yesterday.

Comment: Sorry, again "the latest and largest" makes no sense. (and you just added "since yesterday" as a totally new criterion) What if there is 40 files in total, of which 20 are small, new ones, and 20 old, large ones. what do you want to get in that case?

Comment: If 'latest' means 'since yesterday' (or any specific period, like 'since I last checked'), then 'largest' works by itself. Alternatively, use 'greater than specified size' and order by date. Ranking a list by two independent variables has no meaning. Of course, you could link the variables (down-rank file size by 10% per hour of age).

Comment: Note that `du` will also print the cumulative size of directories, so the top 20 will likely be made mostly of those.